Android spinner is blocked on the first item after receiveing gps signal in my app
So i have the following activity which should chose a plane from a list and go in an activity which uses some gps data.After getting gps signal and going back to the  initial activity to chose another plane the spinner is stuck at the first item.
Here is the activity to chose the plane
package com.example.clear2go;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import com.example.clear2go.databinding.ActivityProfileBinding;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private DatabaseReference avioaneData;
private static final String TAG="GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_TAG";
private ActivityProfileBinding binding;
String[] avioane ={"YR-5659","YR-PBJ","YR-5600","YR-5657"};
String selectedPlane;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
binding  = ActivityProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
Toolbar toolbar = binding.toolbar;
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
avioaneData = mDatabase.getDatabase().getReference().child("Utilizare/Aviatie/Aerodromuri/AR_AT Bucuresti/Flota/Avioane");
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
checkUser();
Spinner selectPlane = binding.spinner;
avioaneData.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
Iterable<DataSnapshot> airplanes = snapshot.getChildren();
            List<String> updatedAvioane = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot airplaneSnapshot : airplanes) {
                String airplaneCode = airplaneSnapshot.getKey();
                updatedAvioane.add(airplaneCode);
            }

            // Update the adapter with the new data
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ProfileActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, updatedAvioane);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            selectPlane.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: database error");
        }
    });
    /*
    selectPlane.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedPlane = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // Do something with the selectedName
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

     */
    selectedPlane= (String) selectPlane.getSelectedItem();

    binding.button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"merge avionu..."+selectPlane.getSelectedItem(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, FlyActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("avion", (String) selectPlane.getSelectedItem());
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    binding.button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,ControlActivity.class));
        }
    });


}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.idk1) {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        checkUser();
    }

    return true;
}

private void checkUser() {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(firebaseUser==null){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }


}

}
and here is the activity for flight:
package com.example.clear2go;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import com.example.clear2go.databinding.ActivityFlyBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
public class FlyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE = 1;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
ActivityFlyBinding binding;
private FusedLocationProviderClient locationClient;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private DatabaseReference avionData;
private DatabaseReference rq;
Sensor pressureSensor;
String avion;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent start = getIntent();
    avion = start.getStringExtra("avion");
    binding = ActivityFlyBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    pressureSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    rq = mDatabase.getDatabase().getReference().child("Requests");
    avionData = mDatabase.getDatabase().getReference().child("Utilizare/Aviatie/Aerodromuri/AR_AT Bucuresti/Flota/Avioane/" + avion);

    binding.engOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rq.child(avion).child("Pornire motor").setValue(false);
            binding.engOn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
        }
    });
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Utilizare/Aviatie/Aerodromuri/AR_AT Bucuresti/Flota/Avioane/" + avion + "/Pornire motor").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                if (snapshot.getValue(boolean.class) == true) {
                    binding.engOn.setBackgroundColor(-16711936);
                    binding.engOn.setActivated(true);
                    binding.taxi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            rq.child(avion).child("Rulaj").setValue(false);
                            binding.taxi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
                        }
                    });
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Utilizare/Aviatie/Aerodromuri/AR_AT Bucuresti/Flota/Avioane/" + avion + "/Rulaj").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                if (snapshot.getValue(boolean.class) == true) {
                                    binding.taxi.setBackgroundColor(-16711936);
                                    binding.taxi.setActivated(true);
                                    binding.lineIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            rq.child(avion).child("Intrare si aliniere").setValue(false);
                                            binding.lineIn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
                                        }
                                    });
                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Utilizare/Aviatie/Aerodromuri/AR_AT Bucuresti/Flota/Avioane/" + avion + "/Intrare si aliniere").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                                if (snapshot.getValue(boolean.class) == true) {
                                                    binding.lineIn.setBackgroundColor(-16711936);
                                                    binding.lineIn.setActivated(true);
                                                    binding.Takeoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                                            rq.child(avion).child("Plecare").setValue(false);
                                                            binding.Takeoff.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Utilizare/Aviatie/Aerodromuri/AR_AT Bucuresti/Flota/Avioane/" + avion + "/Plecare").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                                                if (snapshot.getValue(boolean.class) == true) {
                                                                    binding.Takeoff.setBackgroundColor(-16711936);
                                                                    binding.Takeoff.setActivated(true);

                                                                    binding.land.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                                                            //rq.child(avion).setValue("Aterizare "+avion);
                                                                            rq.child(avion).child("Aterizare").setValue(false);
                                                                            binding.land.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
                                                                        }
                                                                    });
                                                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Utilizare/Aviatie/Aerodromuri/AR_AT Bucuresti/Flota/Avioane/" + avion + "/Aterizare").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                                                                if (snapshot.getValue(boolean.class) == true) {
                                                                                    binding.land.setBackgroundColor(-16711936);
                                                                                    binding.land.setActivated(true);
                                                                                } else {
                                                                                    binding.land.setActivated(false);
                                                                                    binding.land.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }

                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                                                        }
                                                                    });
                                                                } else {
                                                                    binding.Takeoff.setActivated(false);
                                                                    binding.Takeoff.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                                                                    binding.land.setActivated(false);
                                                                    binding.land.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                } else {
                                                    binding.lineIn.setActivated(false);
                                                    binding.lineIn.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                                                    binding.Takeoff.setActivated(false);
                                                    binding.Takeoff.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                                                    binding.land.setActivated(false);
                                                    binding.land.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    binding.taxi.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
                                    binding.taxi.setActivated(false);

                                    binding.lineIn.setActivated(false);
                                    binding.lineIn.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                                    binding.Takeoff.setActivated(false);
                                    binding.Takeoff.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                                    binding.land.setActivated(false);
                                    binding.land.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    binding.engOn.setActivated(false);
                    binding.engOn.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                    binding.taxi.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
                    binding.taxi.setActivated(false);

                    binding.lineIn.setActivated(false);
                    binding.lineIn.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                    binding.Takeoff.setActivated(false);
                    binding.Takeoff.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                    binding.land.setActivated(false);
                    binding.land.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    binding.exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FlyActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
    binding.alt.setText(String.valueOf((int)location.getAltitude()));
    binding.speed.setText(String.valueOf((int)location.getSpeed()));
    avionData.child("lat").setValue(location.getLatitude());
    avionData.child("lng").setValue(location.getLongitude());
}

}
so i tried to elimiante the onItemSelectedListener and used.getItemSelected but no effect

The code you have here is not very well formatted, and therefore difficult to read.  I suggest cleaning that up to make it easier for others to understand what you have so far.  Typically people use markdown code fences to format code blocks.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.
